# bufferevent_openssl.c:60:10: fatal error: 'openssl/bio.h' file not found

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

> bufferevent_openssl.c:60:10: **fatal error: **'openssl/bio.h' file not found

```
#include <openssl/bio.h>

* ^*

1 error generated.

make[2]: *** [bufferevent_openssl.lo] Error 1

make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is the update which I get when I try to instal the libevent. can anyone help me out?

I use a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same issue by installing libevent via brew:

```
brew install libevent
```

It will install the latest libevent.

I am using macOS Sierra.

It will return 404 Error in El-Capitan, Update brew will resolv the problem

Comment: It returned 404 error for me on the el_capitan. Updating brew is worked well!